# How allow pod from default namespace, read secret from other namespace

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-secrets

In Azure Kubernetes I want have a pod with jenkins in defualt namespace, that needs read secret from my aplication workspace.

When I tried I get the next error:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): secrets "myapp-mongodb" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:jenkinspod" cannot get resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "myapp"
```

How I can bring access this jenkisn pod to read secrets in 'myapp' namespace

Comment: What is the role that is assigned to service account of the pod?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`secret` is a namespaced resource and can be accessed via proper rbac permissions. However any improper rbac permissions may lead to leakage.

You must `role bind` the pod's associated service account. Here is a complete example. I have created a new service account for role binding in this example. However, you can use the default `service account` if you want.

step-1: create a namespace called `demo-namespace`

```
kubectl create ns demo-namespace
```

step-2: create a secret in `demo-namespace`:

```
kubectl create  secret generic  other-secret -n demo-namespace  --from-literal foo=bar
secret/other-secret created
```

step-2: Create a service account(`my-custom-sa`) in the `default` namespace.

```
kubectl create sa my-custom-sa
```

step-3: Validate that, by default, the service account you created in the last step has no access to the secrets present in `demo-namespace`.

```
kubectl auth can-i get secret -n demo-namespace --as system:serviceaccount:default:my-custom-sa
no
```

step-4: Create a cluster role with permissions of `get` and `list` secrets from `demo-namespace` namespace.

```
kubectl create clusterrole role-for-other-user --verb get,list --resource secret
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/role-for-other-user created
```

step-5: Create a rolebinding to bind the cluster role created in last step.

```
 kubectl create  rolebinding role-for-other-user -n demo-namespace --serviceaccount default:my-custom-sa --clusterrole  role-for-other-user
 rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/role-for-other-user created
```

step-6: validate that the service account in the default ns now has access to the secrets of `demo-namespace`. (note the difference from step 3)

```
kubectl auth can-i get secret -n demo-namespace --as system:serviceaccount:default:my-custom-sa
yes
```

step-7: create a pod in default namsepace and mount the service account you created earlier.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: my-pod
  name: my-pod
spec:
  serviceAccountName: my-custom-sa
  containers:
  - command:
    - sleep
    - infinity
    image: bitnami/kubectl
    name: my-pod
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

step-7: Validate that you can read the secret of `demo-namespace` from the pod in the default namespace.

```
 curl -sSk -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)"       https://$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST:$KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT/api/v1/namespaces/demo-namespace/secrets
{
  "kind": "SecretList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "resourceVersion": "668709"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "other-secret",
        "namespace": "demo-namespace",
        "uid": "5b3b9dba-be5d-48cc-ab16-4e0ceb3d1d72",
        "resourceVersion": "662043",
        "creationTimestamp": "2022-08-19T14:51:15Z",
        "managedFields": [
          {
            "manager": "kubectl-create",
            "operation": "Update",
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "time": "2022-08-19T14:51:15Z",
            "fieldsType": "FieldsV1",
            "fieldsV1": {
              "f:data": {
                ".": {},
                "f:foo": {}
              },
              "f:type": {}
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "data": {
        "foo": "YmFy"
      },
      "type": "Opaque"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very informative! I am wondering if it is somehow possible to mount the secret somehow in a more user-friendly way? I mean without the need to build a HTTP request with the headers manually, but rather in the definition of the pod/deployment itself?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin the HTTP Request is only used to verify everything did work. In theory you do not have to make this request - It’s just the proof everything is working.

Comment: For a minimal example without the commandline commands, see the "bonus" part at the end of https://stackoverflow.com/a/76210102/511976