# What would need to be done to access Kubernetes secret from another namespace via an environment variable

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I saw many answers and many articles on the internet saying it's not possible to access the secrets of other namespaces.

However, the answer provided in another question [How allow pod from default namespace, read secret from other namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73418121/how-allow-pod-from-default-namespace-read-secret-from-other-namespace/73419051#73419051) suggests that it is actually possible by using the correct RBAC role bindings for the service account.

I know it's not the recommended way and you need to be very careful that secrets are not leaked by these measures. But I prefer such an option to manually copy or automatically sync secrets as suggested in other questions.

The missing puzzle piece I'm missing from that answer is, how to inject such a secret as an environment variable in a deployment using `secretKeyRef` and accessing it without calling the Kubernetes API?

I've created two namespaces `ns1` and `ns2`, a secret `sec` in ns1, a service account `sa` in ns2. See yaml below:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: ns1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: ns2
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: sec
  namespace: ns1
stringData:
  key: value

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sa
  namespace: ns2
```

Trying to the the secret with `kubectl` is not working as expected:

```bash
$ kubectl get secrets sec -n ns1 --as system:serviceaccount:ns2:sa
Error from server (Forbidden): secrets "sec" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:ns2:sa" cannot get resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "ns1"
```

By adding the the required ClusterRole and ClusterRolebinding, the access is possible:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: role-for-sa
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: rolebinding-for-sa
  namespace: ns1
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: role-for-sa
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: sa
    namespace: ns2
```

```bash
$ kubectl get secrets sec -n ns1 --as system:serviceaccount:ns2:sa
NAME   TYPE     DATA   AGE
sec    Opaque   1      8m27s
```

So far so good.

Now I want to use that secret in a Pod in ns2 by using `secretKeyRef` and specifying the service account to be used:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: envpod
  namespace: ns2
spec:
  serviceAccountName: sa
  containers:
  - command:
    - sleep
    - infinity
    image: bitnami/kubectl
    name: envpod
    env:
     - name: MySecret
       valueFrom:
         secretKeyRef:
           key: "key"
           name: sec
    resources: {}
```

But during the pod startup I get the error message `Error: secret "sec" not found`.

```bash
$ kubectl -n ns2 describe pods envpod
...
  Warning  Failed     8s (x2 over 10s)  kubelet            Error: secret "sec" not found
...
```

I tried it also with `sec.ns1` but didn't help either.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this? Or explanation why this is not possible that way?

Comment: The question you link to describes a very manual path to retrieve a secret using the Kubernetes API.  That's possible, given an appropriate ServiceAccount and RBAC settings and writing code to retrieve the Secret value. As you note in the first paragraph a Pod can only directly attach to other resources in its own namespace (Secrets, ConfigMaps, PersistentVolumeClaims, _etc._) without writing this manual code.  The linked question describes several alternative approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading environment variable from a secret object from different namespace is not supported out of the box. You Need to use a startup script ( docker entrypoint ) to fetch the secret object from remote namespace and load them as environment variable inside the pod and then start the main process in the pod